# sweetalert2 multiple swal at the same function

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'd like to make a condition and call a swal for each one (Sweetalert2). But only one of the swal runs. How can I do it?

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  var regex = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
  return regex.test(email);
}

function validateBirth(data) {
  var regex = /^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;
  return regex.test(data);
}

function validacao() {
  var data = document.getElementById('birth').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  if (!validateBirth(data)) {
    swal(
      'title..',
      'text..',
      'type..'
    );
  }
  if (!validateEmail(email)) {
    swal(
      'title..',
      'text..',
      'type..'
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update 2021:**

Just make your function `async` and `await` promises from `Swal.fire()`:

```js
async function validacao() {
  var data = document.getElementById('birth').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  if (!validateBirth(data)) {
    await Swal.fire(
      'title..',
      'text..',
      'type..'
    );
  }
  if (!validateEmail(email)) {
    await Swal.fire(
      'title..',
      'text..',
      'type..'
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Old answer which will not work for latest versions of SweetAlert2:**

There's [`swal.queue()`](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#chaining-modals), use it for multiple modals.

Your case should look like this:

```
var modals = [];

// birth modal
if (!validateBirth(data)) {
  modals.push({title: 'title1', text: 'text1', ... });
}

// email modal
if (!validateEmail(email)) {
  modals.push({title: 'title2', text: 'text2', ... });
}

Swal.queue(modals);
```

Comment: Nice. I'll try this out later.

Comment: Works like a charm ;)